# SQL returns incorrect data using 2 left joins

Tags: mysql

I have written a MYSQL script, that returns incorrect data. I am quite fluent in SQL, but this query is not returning correct results. Can someone have a look and see whats going on. The problem is the  noOfBids, and noOfRatedTimes. The values are the same for both columns and are large values too.

```
    select
           a.user_name as userName,
           coalesce(count(b.sp_user_name),0) as noOfBids,
           coalesce(ROUND(AVG(b.a_amount),2),0) as avgAmount,
           coalesce(count(d.sp_user_name),0) as noOfRatedTimes,
           coalesce(ROUND(AVG(d.user_rate),2),0)
    from users a
    left join project_imds b
       on b.sp_user_name = a.user_name
    left join projects c
       on b.project_code = c.project_code
    left join sp_user_rating d
       on d.sp_user_name = b.sp_user_name
    where a.user_type = 'SP'
    and a.active = 'Y'
    group by a.user_name
    order by coalesce(ROUND(AVG(d.user_rate),2),0) desc;
```

I have created a workaround on this, by creating a temp table to get the avg values and joining this to the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the specifics of the data behind your query, this is only a guess. But perhaps you'd rather join "sp_user_rating" directly to "users", changing

```
left join sp_user_rating d
   on d.sp_user_name = b.sp_user_name
```

to

```
left join sp_user_rating d
   on d.sp_user_name = a.user_name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select
       a.user_name as userName,
       coalesce(count(b.sp_user_name),0) as noOfBids,
       coalesce(ROUND(AVG(b.a_amount),2),0) as avgAmount,
       coalesce(count(d.sp_user_name),0) as noOfRatedTimes,
       coalesce(ROUND(AVG(d.user_rate),2),0)
from users as a
left join project_imds as b
   on b.sp_user_name = a.user_name
left join projects as c
   on b.project_code = c.project_code
left join sp_user_rating as d
   on d.sp_user_name = b.sp_user_name
where a.user_type = 'SP'
and a.active = 'Y'
group by a.user_name
order by coalesce(ROUND(AVG(d.user_rate),2),0) desc;
```

Comment: Why is this different / of help?

Comment: I too dont see any difference between original query and this one?

Comment: use of AS keyword added to the query